# Two RecyclerViews one Adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have two RecyclerViews that use same adapter in My fragment like this

```
RecyclerView rvFirst;
RecyclerView rvSecond;
ArrayList<Data> alFirst;
ArrayList<Data> alSecond;
AdapterBoth adapterFirst;
AdapterBoth adapterSecond;

 ...

 rvFirst = (RecyclerView) myView.findViewById(R.id.rvFirst);
        adapterFirst = new AdapterBoth(alFirst);
        rvFirst.setAdapter(adapterFirst);
        rvFirst.setLayoutManager(mLayoutFirst);
        adapterFirst.setOnItemClickListner(new AdapterBoth.onItemClickListner() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(int id) {
                showAcceptDialog(id, TYPE_ONE);
            }
        });

        rvSecond = (RecyclerView) myView.findViewById(R.id.rvSecond);
        adapterSecond = new AdapterBoth(alSecond);
        rvSecond.setAdapter(adapterSecond);
        rvSecond.setLayoutManager(mLayoutSecond);
        adapterSecond.setOnItemClickListner(new AdapterBoth.onItemClickListner() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(int id) {
                showAcceptDialog(id, TYPE_TWO);
            }
        });
```

and i fetch data like this

```
private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

     ...

            jsonDataSet1 = data.getJSONArray("dataSet1");
            jsonDataSet2 = data.getJSONArray("dataSet2");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonDataSet1.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject o = jsonDataSet1.getJSONObject(i);
                alFirst.add(new Data(o.getInt(TAG_ID), o.getString(TAG_DATE), o.getString(TAG_NAME)));

            }
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonDataSet2.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject u = jsonDataSet2.getJSONObject(i);
                alSecond.add(new Data(u.getInt(TAG_ID), u.getString(TAG_DATE), u.getString(TAG_NAME)));

            }

            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {

        adapterFirst.notifyDataSetChanged();
        adapterSecond.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

But the problem is that both RecyclerViews show the same data or better to say the data of the last initialized RecyclerView (if i swap the position of adapter init the last one will be shown in both) i can see different sizes (`Log.d(ArrayList.size())`)  and diferent data (if i do `Log.d(JsonObject.toString())`)

I am sure i have different instances of Adapters for each RecyclerView, but they act as i set the same on both. I think it has to do with RecyclerView but i am not sure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside your "doInBackground" you have a mistake, in second loop you are using variable "u" but inserting values from variable "o" from first loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonDataSet1.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject o = jsonDataSet1.getJSONObject(i);
            alFirst.add(new Data(o.getInt(TAG_ID), o.getString(TAG_DATE), o.getString(TAG_NAME)));

        }
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonDataSet2.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject u = jsonDataSet2.getJSONObject(i);
            alSecond.add(new Data(o.getInt(TAG_ID), o.getString(TAG_DATE), o.getString(TAG_NAME)));

        }
```

Should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonDataSet1.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject o = jsonDataSet1.getJSONObject(i);
            alFirst.add(new Data(o.getInt(TAG_ID), o.getString(TAG_DATE), o.getString(TAG_NAME)));

        }
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonDataSet2.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject u = jsonDataSet2.getJSONObject(i);
            alSecond.add(new Data(u.getInt(TAG_ID), u.getString(TAG_DATE), u.getString(TAG_NAME)));

        }
```

Comment: Yeah that was my mistake copy, pasting and changing... Sorry about that. But i did went to check that also just in case and that isn't the problem ( i am getting the same issue). But thank you for noticing that

Comment: Well i found it it was my mistake... i put for some dumb reason in constructor of adapter that passed data is static. So i am going to put this as answered since you did direct me in searching for my mistakes... so ty for that